# Generating random time with intervals of 5 minutes

Tags: python, datetime, random

I'm trying to get an output that looks like that:

```
12:15
07:55
02:20
04:35
```

I managed to get the following output:

```
2020-07-03 03:53:32
2020-07-20 08:01:15
2020-07-29 10:04:11
2020-07-07 07:17:24
2020-07-20 12:13:32
```

by using this code:

```
import datetime
import time
import random

MINTIME = datetime.datetime(2020,7,1,0,0,0)
MAXTIME = datetime.datetime(2020,7,31,0,0,0)

mintime_ts = int(time.mktime(MINTIME.timetuple())) #convert date into int
maxtime_ts = int(time.mktime(MAXTIME.timetuple())) #convert date into int

for RECORD in range(100):
    random_ts = random.randint(mintime_ts, maxtime_ts)
    RANDOMTIME = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(random_ts)
    print(RANDOMTIME)
```

So, basically I have two issues. The first is I want to get the time in format of (hh:mm) only. The second is that I want the step to be 5 minutes (something like 14:50 or 04:35 .. etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the number of 5 minutes slots between your min and max time, and choose one of these slots randomly.

For the output, use the `strftime` method to get any format you want:

```
import datetime
import time
import random

MINTIME = datetime.datetime(2020,7,1,0,0,0)
MAXTIME = datetime.datetime(2020,7,31,0,0,0)

mintime_ts = int(time.mktime(MINTIME.timetuple())) #convert date into int
maxtime_ts = int(time.mktime(MAXTIME.timetuple())) #convert date into int

nb_slots = (maxtime_ts - mintime_ts)//(5*60)  # number of 5 minutes slots
for RECORD in range(10):
    random_slot = random.randint(0, nb_slots)
    random_ts = mintime_ts + 5*60 * random_slot
    RANDOMTIME = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(random_ts)
    print(datetime.datetime.strftime(RANDOMTIME, '%H:%M'))
```

Output:

```
11:20
15:20
11:25
02:10
13:30
08:30
00:45
06:10
17:05
01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import time
import random

MINTIME = datetime.datetime(2020,7,1,0,0,0)
MAXTIME = datetime.datetime(2020,7,31,0,0,0)

mintime_ts = int(time.mktime(MINTIME.timetuple())) #convert date into int
maxtime_ts = int(time.mktime(MAXTIME.timetuple())) #convert date into int

scale = 5*60

for RECORD in range(100):
    random_ts = random.randint(mintime_ts//scale, maxtime_ts//scale)*scale
    RANDOMTIME = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(random_ts)
    print(RANDOMTIME.strftime('%H:%M'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the time in seconds, so you could simply divide `mintime_ts` and `maxtime_ts` by 300 (60*5) and then multiply the result from randint back by 300.

With this, you are randomly selecting a 5 min timestamp between the min and max you defined.

```py
random_ts = random.randint(mintime_ts//300, maxtime_ts//300)*300
```

For the formatting part, you can use [datetime's strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

```py
print(RANDOMTIME.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

*Sidenote*: You can also use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) to sample random numbers with replacement (meaning that the number can be selected more than once). The advantage is that you can tell the function to give you all the numbers you want at once.

```py
random.choices(
    # Define the population of numbers you want it to select from.
    # In your case this is any number that is a multiple of 300 (because of the 5 min)
    population=range(mintime_ts//300*300, maxtime_ts, 300),
    k=100 # Define how many numbers you want
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas

```
In [15]: import pandas as pd

In [16]: [i.strftime("%H:%M") for i in pd.date_range("01:13", "01:57", freq="5min").time]
Out[16]:
['01:13',
 '01:18',
 '01:23',
 '01:28',
 '01:33',
 '01:38',
 '01:43',
 '01:48',
 '01:53']
```

Comment: This is overkill to use pandas for so simple task

Comment: I just gave an option, it's left to OP

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use datetime functions, just use random functions for generate random integers in specified interval:

```
import random

for RECORD in range(100):
  print(
    #generate random int between 0 and 23 convert to string and pad by '0'
    str(random.randint(0,23)).rjust(2,'0') 
    # add devider
    + ':' + 
    # random int between 0 and 55 with step 5
    str(random.randint(0,11)*5).rjust(2,'0') 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should help:

#Necessary packages

```
import datetime
import random
import numpy as np
```

#Define the minute range (0-55, 60 means 0) with step-size of 5

```
minute_range = np.arange(0,59,5)
```

#Define the hours range (0,23, 24 means 00)

```
hour_range = np.arange(0,24,1)
```

#randomly pick hour and minute and convert it into time object

```
a = datetime.time(random.choice(hour_range),random.choice(minute_range))
```

#convert the object to string

```
print(a.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

## a loop to serve as the demonstration:

```
for _ in range(5):
    a = datetime.time(random.choice(hour_range),random.choice(minute_range))
    print(a.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

#Output:

```
05:25
09:55
07:05
08:05
11:05
```

I hope I could help.